# Is there a Facebook SDK for iOS?

Tags: iphone, facebook

Is any API for Facebook where we can check our wall and our home page wall
and more we can post comment, post on friends wall, update our status etc. if we have authorization details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is an API!

See:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

and:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Comment: Graphic API and Old REST API
which one should be good. if I need to integrate fb in any app

Comment: i found tutorial for new graphic API in Iphone.. have you any link of tutorial of Old REST API for the same

Comment: you should use the new graph api,if applicable